# CakePHP - get last query run

Tags: mysql, logging, cakephp

I want to get the last query CakePHP ran. I can't turn debug on in core.php and I can't run the code locally. I need a way to get the last sql query and log it to the error log without effecting the live site. This query is failing but is being run.

something like this would be great:

```
$this->log($this->ModelName->lastQuery);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 49):

For Cake 2.0, the query log is protected so this will work

```
function getLastQuery() {
  $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
  $logs = $dbo->getLog();
  $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
  return $lastLog['query'];
}
```

Comment: I checked above function and its working fine if debug mode is 2 but its not returning query if debug mode is 0 . is there any another solution?

Answer (score 32):

Tested in CakePHP v2.3.2

```
$log = $this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
debug($log);
```

Comment: This worked great for me. Make sure to have the debug level set above 1 in core.php

Answer (score 29):

In CakePHP 1.x, the data you want is accessible in `DataSource::_queriesLog`. Cake doesn't really provide a getter method for this member, but the underlying language being PHP, nothing stops you from doing the following:

In `app/app_model.php`:

```
function getLastQuery()
{
    $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
    $logs = $dbo->_queriesLog;

    return end($logs);
}
```

Comment: When I try using this function I only get "2010-03-29 11:13:29 Error: " in the error log file. I used $this->log($this->Job->getLastQuery());

Comment: $this->log(var_export($this->Job->getLastQuery(),true));

Comment: Where are you calling $this->log()? Also, you might want to debug the output from Model::getLastQuery before throwing it in the log. It might be returning an array, causing an array-to-string conversion error.

Comment: I had to do:
    $query = end($logs);
    return $query['query'];

Either the format of the _queriesLog changed, or the above code returned an array of data about the query rather than simply the query itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this inline.

```
$dbo = $this->Model->getDatasource();
// store old state
$oldStateFullDebug = $dbo->fullDebug;
// turn fullDebug on
$dbo->fullDebug = true;

// Your code here! eg.
$this->Model->find('all');

// write to logfile
// use print_r with second argument to return a dump of the array
Debugger::log(print_r($dbo->_queriesLog, true));
// restore fullDebug
$dbo->fullDebug = $oldStateFullDebug;
```

Comment: gives an error `Cannot access protected property Mysql::$_queriesLog `, cake 2.3

Answer (score 4):

This is a very late answer, i know, but for whoever needs this in the future, you can always restrict setting debug to your IP, For example:

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == '192.168.0.100'){
Configure::write('debug', 2); //Enables debugging only for your IP.
}
```

Comment: you can even make a debug method in one of your controllers that sets a session variable true/false and sets the debug config variable accordingly.

Comment: Alinn, if access to that method is not secured properly it could lead to a security exploit where anyone could enable debug mode.  Be careful.

Answer (score 4):

Simple you can use showLog() function

```
var_dump($this->YourModel->getDataSource()->showLog());
```

Answer (score 3):

Combination of Matt's and blavia's solution (works when debug is not 2):

```
$dbo = $this->Model->getDatasource();
$oldStateFullDebug = $dbo->fullDebug;
$dbo->fullDebug = true;
// find or whatever...
$this->Model->find("all");
$logs = $dbo->getLog();
$lastLog = end($logs['log']);
CakeLog::write("DBLog", $lastLog['query']);
$dbo->fullDebug = $oldStateFullDebug;
```

Answer (score 2):

Having a quick skim of the book, [cakephp api getLog](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DboSource.html#_getLog) you could turn on `logTransaction`. Although having not used it, I'm not sure how it will perform.

Otherwise you could experiment with [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) and here is the a [guide for it](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/debugging-with-firephp),

You might try [DebugKit](http://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit), although off the top of my head I think you do still need debug 2 to get it to work.

Hopefully something might give you a lead. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$log = $this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);

pr($log);die;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to view the query in CakePHP.

Both methods you have to add the below one line in app/Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

First methods :

```
debug($this->getLastQuery());
```

where you want to get the query add above line and call this function `getLastQuery()` on same controller using below code

```
public function getLastQuery() {
    $dbo = $this->TModel->getDatasource();  //Here TModel is a model.what table you want to print 
    $logs = $dbo->getLog();
    $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
    return $lastLog['query'];
}
```

second method :

add the below line in the any Elements files.

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
echo '<pre>';
$log = $this->YOUR_MODEL->getDataSource(); 
print_r($log);
exit;
```