# How to create a `IN` clause in CakePHP query?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

How do you make it where in clause in new CakePHP? I'm trying:

```
$restaurants->find()->where(['id' => $r_ids])->all();
```

Where `$r_ids` is array of ids I need in my query, but this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With CakePHP 3.x it's now necessary to either indicate the data type, which for an array of values need to have `[]` appended to the type:

```
$query = $articles
    ->find()
    ->where(['id' => $ids], ['id' => 'integer[]']);
```

or to explicitly make use of the `IN` keyword:

```
$query = $articles
    ->find()
    ->where(['id IN' => $ids]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Automatically Creating IN Clauses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses)**

Comment: If we have to check multiple columns in IN clause then how to do?  What to do in this case : ->where(['id,name IN' => ??]);

Comment: @rack_nilesh You'll have to use the tuple comparison expression: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/37924543/1392379**

Comment: tysm. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for CakePHP 3.x

```
$query = $restaurants
    ->find()
    ->where(['id IN' => $r_ids]);
$query->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the short syntax:

```php
    $result = $restaurants->find('all', 
            ['conditions' => ['id IN' =>$r_ids]]
        )->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cakephp 3.x, If you have multiple where conditions then your query will be as below:

```
return $this
        ->find()
        ->contain([
            'XYZ.Articles',
            'YYY.Managers',
            'ZZZ.Readers',
        ])
        ->where([
            'ID' => $ids,
            'READER.STATUS' => $xyz,
        ],[
            'ID' => 'integer[]'
        ])
        ;
```