# Cakephp 3 table updateAll using array

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In [Cakephp 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions)'s model updateAll, we were using arrays as conditions. But this doesn't work :

```
$data=array(12, 22, 44);
TableRegistry::get('Foobar')->updateAll(
   array("checked" => 1),
   array("user_id" => $data) 
 );
```

Is this not possible in Cakephp 3's [updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates) ?

This works in cakephp 3:

```
$data=12;
TableRegistry::get('Foobar')->updateAll(
   array("checked" => 1),
   array("user_id" => $data) 
 );
```

Regarding to [API docs](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_updateAll), `$conditions` defined like this:

```
updateAll( array $fields , mixed $conditions )

array $fields
A hash of field => new value.

mixed $conditions
Conditions to be used, accepts anything Query::where() can take.
```

Edit:
In case of cake works well and I'm making a mistake. How can I understand the cause ? Because when condition is an integer, code works well.

Edit2:
This also works well:

```
 $data=array(12, 22, 44);
 ConnectionManager::get('default')->query('UPDATE foobars SET checked=1 
     WHERE user_id IN ('.implode(",",$data).')')->execute();
```

Comment: You are missing the second argument in the function call

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand. Do you mean updateAll function ?

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887511/where-in-clause** I hope you are aware that your raw query is prone to SQL injections in case `$data` will be user input!

Comment: Thank you ndm. Yes, thats why I need to create a cakephp type query, rather than a raw query. I suppose the problem is missing of IN keyword. I couldnt see it in orm migration notes. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html Also I would be happy to accept your reply as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, as explained in the docs:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates

Comment: Is there a test case that checks for updateAll, with array conditions that has one key and multiple values ? https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=updateAll

Comment: It seems like there is not... What does you intuition says about it? How would you use multiple `set` and multiple condiitions?

Comment: I updated question, you can see from edit2 that, `Connection->query()` works well for this situation. I suppose I make a mistake using `updateAll` method. But not yet found the cause.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the discussion, but since I had a similar problem, using something like *id in array* condition, this is how is done now on Cakephp 3.

```
//using the same example
$data=array(12, 22, 44);

TableRegistry::get('Foobar')->updateAll(
   ["checked" => 1],
   ["user_id IN " => $data] //mind the IN on the condition
);
```

Here is another way from the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#updating-data), updated for the example

```
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$data=array(12, 22, 44);

$query = $articles->query();
$query->update()
    ->set(['checked' => true])
    ->where(['user_id IN' => $data])
    ->execute();
```

Hope it helps someone else.