# query builder: IN clause with composite columns

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to create a IN conditions on multiple columns, like this

```
...
WHERE 
(order_date, order_number) IN (
    ('2016-03-11', 3455453), 
    ('2016-03-18', 83545454), 
    ('2016-06-17', 5354544)
)
```

starting from an array like this:

```
$orders = [
    ['2016-03-11', 3455453], 
    ['2016-03-18', 83545454], 
    ['2016-06-17', 5354544]
];
```

using cake3 query builder. I tried with

```
->where(['(order_date, order_number) IN' => $orders]);
```

but I get an error:

> Cannot convert value to string

I know it's not hard to manually create the query manipulating the array, but I'd like to know if there is a cake way to do it.

Comment: Is what you're trying to do [valid IN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)? I think you're looking for `OR`.

Comment: Oh `IN can be used to compare row constructors: ` - heh never knew/read that. I don't expect there to be a built in way to do that, it's not in common usage (IME, at least).

Comment: I think it is a valid IN syntax. In fact the manual says _IN can be used to compare row constructors_. Also it works in my application (even if I agree that not always _works_ means _it's valid_). Of course I can replace it with an equivalent OR clause but the IN seems more compact in my opinion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAICT this is not possible (yet) using the array syntax or regular comparison expressions, the code responsible for transforming only handles single fields and flat arrays, see

**[Source > \Cake\Database\Expression\Comparison::_stringExpression()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.10/src/Database/Expression/Comparison.php#L179)**

However, this is very well possible using a tuple comparison expression, which supports handling sets of tuples out of the box. Internally it is used by associations for handling composite keys.

```
$fields = ['order_date', 'order_number'];
$types = ['date', 'integer'];
$values = [
    ['2016-03-11', 3455453], 
    ['2016-03-18', 83545454], 
    ['2016-06-17', 5354544]
];

$query->where(
    new \Cake\Database\Expression\TupleComparison($fields, $values, $types, 'IN')
);
```

**[Source > \Cake\Database\Expression\TupleComparison](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.10/src/Database/Expression/TupleComparison.php)**