# How to use more than one column inside MySQL IN clause in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to execute following SQL through CakePHP 3.x as mentioned below:

```
SELECT
 COL1,
 COL2,
 COL3
FROM
 Selections
WHERE
 ROW (COL1, COL2) NOT IN (
  ROW (1, 1),
  ROW (2, 2)
 );
```

I have stored the values to be filtered as an array

```
$filter = [[1 ,1], [2, 2]];
```

In CakePHP 3.x controller, I am trying to execute following Query:

```
$conditions['ROW (Selections.COL1, Selections.COL2) NOT IN'] = $filter;
$options = [
    'limit'      => 1,
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order'      => ['Selections.created' => 'asc']
];
debug($this->Selections->find('all', $options));
$selections = $this->Selections->find('all', $options);
```

This execution results in failure due to following CakePHP 3.x error:

```
Cannot convert value to string
InvalidArgumentException
```

On debugging the Object, I found that it does not have the correct parameter type (marked in bold below):

```
'params' => [
    ':c0' => [
        'value' => [
            (int) 0 => [
                (int) 0 => (int) 1,
                (int) 1 => (int) 1
            ],
            (int) 1 => [
                (int) 0 => (int) 2,
                (int) 1 => (int) 2
            ]
        ],
        'type' => **null**,
        'placeholder' => 'c2'
    ]
],
```

As per my understanding the type should be 'integer[][]' in order to allow proper conversion of double dimensional array to string. However, the type being null is probably interfering with proper conversion.

As an alternative, I made an attempt to implode the `$filter` array thereby converting it into proper string with correct set of brackets and delimiters like this:

```
$filter[] = 'ROW '.implode(', ', [1, 1]);
$conditions['ROW (Selections.COL1, Selections.COL2) NOT IN'] = '('.implode(', ', $filter).')';
```

This correctly converted the array into string for me but CakePHP goes a step ahead and encapsulates the generated string within quotes. This results in following query which throws error during execution on the MySQL db server.

```
SELECT
 COL1,
 COL2,
 COL3
FROM
 Selections
WHERE
 ROW (COL1, COL2) NOT IN '(
  ROW (1, 1),
  ROW (2, 2)
 )';
```

Please note the extra quote after `NOT IN` and before bracket.

I am looking for one of the following solutions:

1. Is there a way to specify the correct parameter type that would
   help CakePHP with proper conversion to string of the double
   dimensional array ?
2. If I attempt string conversion myself, as
   mentioned above, how can I avoid automatic placement of quotes ?

I would also appreciate additional information on why CakePHP 3.x is assigning parameter type as NULL in above situation and ways in which this can be avoided.

If there are alternate methods to handle this case in CakePHP then an attempt to explain it won't go without my sincere appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the second approach of generating string equivalent myself, it is extremely easy to solve this problem:

```
$filter[] = 'ROW '.implode(', ', [1, 1]);
$conditions['ROW (Selections.COL1, Selections.COL2) NOT IN'] = '('.implode(', ', $filter).')';
```

second line should be replaced with:

```
$conditions['ROW (Printouts.user_id, Printouts.receiver) NOT IN ('.implode(',',$dispatched).')'];
```

Damn ! it took less than a line change to solve a problem description that expanded to 2 pages. Basically, one can avoid the `'key' => 'value'` format of specifying the condition and just specify the whole condition as `'value'` only.

Comment: And with this you have created a possible SQL injection vulnerability, as "value only entries" are not going to be subject to escaping/binding. What you are looking for are [**tuple comparisons**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919141/query-builder-in-clause-with-composite-columns/37924543)!

Comment: True ! In my case its an internal script not exposed to outside world. However, intent should be to avoid such a solution. Thanks @ndm for pointing out the correct solution.