# Use array in pagination conditions [CakePHP 3]

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I want to use an array of ids as a condition to my paginate function, but I get this error 'Cannot convert value to integer', I understand that a array is not an integer, but how could I make the condition look for all the values in the array.

```
$friendsid = explode(',', $this->Auth->user('friends'));
$this->paginate = [ 
    'conditions' => [
        'Users.id' => $friendsid,
    ]
]; 
$this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
$this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887511/how-to-create-a-in-clause-in-cakephp-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a \`IN\` clause in CakePHP query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887511/how-to-create-a-in-clause-in-cakephp-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it:

```
$friendsid = explode(',', $this->Auth->user('friends'));
$query     = $this->Users->find() 
                ->where(function ($exp, $q) use ($friendsid) {
                    return $exp->in('Users.id', $friendsid);
                });
$this->set('users', $this->paginate($query));
$this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
```