# Printing data with condition equal to array of ids using cake php

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to print the data from that query where the bstockBooksTableResearchIds is equal array(1,2,3) , but i'm getting error showing in bellow :

```
$bstockBooksTableResearches = $this->BstockIn->BstockResearchs->find('list', [
            'conditions' => ['BstockResearchs.id' => $bstockBooksTableResearchIds],

                ]) ;
```

[image]

Comment: That's not an error, that's the dump of a query object, as the `(help)` key contents indicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a \`IN\` clause in CakePHP query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887511/how-to-create-a-in-clause-in-cakephp-query)

Answer (score 1):

you should add `IN` in your conditions so your code will be

```
$bstockBooksTableResearches = $this->BstockIn->BstockResearchs->find('list', [
            'conditions' => [
                'BstockResearchs.id IN' => $bstockBooksTableResearchIds
                ]
            ]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $bstockBooksTableResearches = $this->BstockIn->BstockResearchs->find('list', array(
                'conditions' =>array (
    'BstockResearchs.id' => $bstockBooksTableResearchIds),

                    )) ;
```

changes: IN clause should be in array.

Comment: **square braces are not allowed** where it was said ?? @Sucharitha

Comment: @tarikul05 : In my case for direct values square braces are working but in variables it raised error. so i thought it may not work.

Comment: it's may be your php version problem, PHP doc says **As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].**  so it allow for all. You can't say **not allowed**.