# CakePHP 2.9 join query returning wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm

I'm using the following (working) MySQL query to get a count of all the collection_items for a collection_keyword

```
SELECT ck.id
     , ck.working_title
     , count(*) as matches 
  FROM collection_keywords ck
  JOIN collection_keywords_collection_items ckci 
    ON ckci.collection_keyword_id = ck.id
  JOIN nl_collection_items nci 
    ON nci.id = ckci.collection_item_id
 GROUP 
    BY ck.id
```

#### SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b4b0a/1

Which returns the following information

```
+----+---------------+---------+
| id | working_title | matches |
+----+---------------+---------+
|  1 | First Title   |       5 |
|  2 | Second Title  |      10 |
|  3 | Third Title   |      15 |
+----+---------------+---------+
```

I'm trying to replicate this query using CakePHP 2.9., using the join method but

### **the result is returning empty**

This is my CakePHP code

```
$collectionKeywords = $this->CollectionKeyword->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(),
    'fields' => array('CollectionKeyword.id, CollectionKeyword.working_title', 'count(*) AS matches'),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'collection_keywords_collection_items',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'collection_keywords_collection_items.collection_keyword_id' => 'CollectionKeyword.id'
            )
        )
    ),
    'group' => 'CollectionKeyword.id',
));
```

The relations are defined as follows

```
class CollectionKeyword extends PluginCollectionKeyword
{
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'CollectionItem' => array(
            'className' => 'CollectionItem',
            'joinTable' => 'collection_keywords_collection_items',
            'foreignKey' => 'collection_keyword_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'collection_item_id',
        )
    );
}
```

And the CollectionItem relation

```
class CollectionItem extends PluginCollectionItem
{

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'CollectionKeyword' => array(
            'className' => 'CollectionKeyword',
            'joinTable' => 'collection_keywords_collection_items',
            'foreignKey' => 'collection_item_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'collection_keyword_id',
        ),

    );
}
```

Comment: Added SQLFiddle. Thanks @Strawberry

Comment: (Actually, probably wasn't required in this instance, but +1 anyway)

Comment: Which version of Cakephp are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.9.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues I found in your code:

1. The array key for Join should be `joins`. You have used `join`.
2. The condition for 2nd Inner Join is missing.

Here is the code that worked.

```
 $collectionKeywords = $this->CollectionKeyword->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(),
    'fields' => array('CollectionKeyword.id, CollectionKeyword.working_title', 'count(*) AS matches'),
    'recursive' => -1,
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'collection_keywords_collection_items',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                "collection_keywords_collection_items.collection_keyword_id = CollectionKeyword`.id"
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'collection_items',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                "collection_items.id = collection_keywords_collection_items.collection_item_id"
            )
        ),        
    ),
    'group' => 'CollectionKeyword.id',
    ));
```

It produces the below query

```
SELECT CollectionKeyword.id, CollectionKeyword.working_title, count(*) AS matches FROM `collection_keywords` AS `CollectionKeyword` INNER JOIN `collection_keywords_collection_items` ON (`collection_keywords_collection_items`.`collection_keyword_id` = `CollectionKeyword`.`id`) INNER JOIN `collection_items` ON (`collection_items`.`id` = `collection_keywords_collection_items`.`collection_item_id`) WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `CollectionKeyword`.`id`
```

Depending upon the Cakephp Version that you are using, you can verify the Last Query which ran by using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521225/cakephp-get-last-query-run).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It also works without the second join, since I don't need any data from that table, I see now that I was using array notation for the join conditions, which is false.

Comment: @Notflip Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.