# How to get sql query in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp framework. I need SQL for following statement:

`$vehicle = $this->Vehicle->find('all');`

How can I do that?

Please guide me.

Thank you,
Trupti

Comment: Which version of Cakephp you are using?

Comment: Version is 1.2.5

Comment: Check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521225/cakephp-get-last-query-run

Comment: Enable debug and add <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?> in footer, so that you can view all the sql queries in pages while developing

Comment: I'm curious why a new user is using a [10 year old version](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/1.2.5) of a framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Cakephp 1.x, you could use following code to get the last query

```
    $dbo = $this->Vehicle->getDatasource();
    $logs = $dbo->getLog();
    $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
    echo $lastLog['query'];
```

Alternatively, To get all the Queries executed in the Current HTTP Request, you can use the following code

```
$db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db->showLog();
```

You have to set the Debug Mode to 2 for this to work.

Comment: Getting this error:  Call to undefined method DboMysql::getLog()